# Register Library in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My directory structure looks like

```
app/
 config/
 data/
 libraries/
  Erfurt/
 /module
 /public
 /vendor
```

I want to use the Erfurt library. Erfurt dont use namespaces but a vendor-underscore-class naming convention, e. g. `class Erfurt_App`.

I've found different answers on the web but nothing helps me. Here is what I've tested:

**app/module/module.php**

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
            'prefixes' => array(
                'Erfurt' =>  __DIR__ . '/../libraries/Erfurt/',
            ),
        ),

    );
}
```

If I try to use a Erfurt class, PHP is unable to found it.

```
$erfurt = \Erfurt_App::getInstance();
```

It says

> Fatal error: Class 'Erfurt_App' not found in (...)\app\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\ApplicationController.php
>   on line 24

What is the right way to include the Erfurt library in my app?

Comment: drop library into vendor folder and specify composer classmap autoloading for that library in application's composer.json, unless you can install library using composer

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Xerkus comment, this how it works:

1. Moved the [Erfurt](https://github.com/AKSW/Erfurt/tree/develop/library/Erfurt) directory from **app/libraries/Erfurt** to **app/vendor/Erfurt**
2. Additional, Erfurt needs an older Zend version, so I also extracted **[ontowiki-0.9.6-21.7z/ontowiki-0.9.6-21/libraries/Zend](https://github.com/AKSW/OntoWiki/downloads)** into **app/libraries/Zend**
3. Added classmap to **app/composer.json**:

`"autoload":{
        "classmap": ["vendor/Erfurt", "vendor/Zend"]
    },`

4. Becouse Erfurt includes Zend classes via `require_once 'Zend/Version.php';` I also needed to add the include-path to **app/composer.json**:

`"include-path": ["vendor"]`

Now I can use Erfurt with:

```
$erfurt = \Erfurt_App::getInstance();
```

Finally **app/composer.json** looks like:

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
        "cpliakas/git-wrapper": "~1.0"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "classmap": ["vendor/Erfurt", "vendor/Zend"]
    },
    "include-path": ["vendor"]
}
```

Comment: you can specify zf1 svn repo in composer, see: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories and then require as `"zendframework/zendframework1": "~1.11"`

Comment: But i recommend you to check if it works with 1.12.x, which have bug fixes and available as `zendframework/zendframework1` in packagist